# How to change AnimationTimer speed?

Tags: java, animation, timer, javafx

I use `AnimationTimer` for several tasks like animation with changing pictures and `ProgressIndicator` animation. To achieve needed speed I put thread to sleep, but when several animations are running simultaneously they affect each others speed. Is there any other way to change speed of `AnimationTimer`? Code sample:

```
private void initialize() {
 programButtonAnimation=new AnimationTimer(){
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                    showClockAnimation();
            }
        };
 programButtonAnimation.start();
}

private void showClockAnimation(){
    String imageName = "%s_"+"%05d"+".%s";
    String picturePath="t093760/diploma/view/styles/images/pink_frames/"+String.format( imageName,"pink" ,frameCount,"png");
    programButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image:url('"+picturePath+"')");
    frameCount++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(28);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(frameCount>=120){
        programButtonAnimation.stop();
        frameCount=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `AnimationTimer`'s `handle` method is invoked once for each frame that is rendered, on the FX Application Thread. You should never block that thread, so do not call `Thread.sleep(...)` here.

The parameter passed to the `handle(...)` method is a timestamp, in nanoseconds. So if you want to throttle updates so they don't happen more than once every, say 28 milliseconds, you can use this to do so:

```
private void initialize() {
 programButtonAnimation=new AnimationTimer(){

            private long lastUpdate = 0 ;
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                    if (now - lastUpdate >= 28_000_000) {
                        showClockAnimation();
                        lastUpdate = now ;
                    }
            }
        };
 programButtonAnimation.start();
}

private void showClockAnimation(){
    String imageName = "%s_"+"%05d"+".%s";
    String picturePath="t093760/diploma/view/styles/images/pink_frames/"+String.format( imageName,"pink" ,frameCount,"png");
    programButton.setStyle("-fx-background-image:url('"+picturePath+"')");
    frameCount++;
    if(frameCount>=120){
        programButtonAnimation.stop();
        frameCount=0;
    }
}
```

Comment: For more ideas about using `AnimationTimer`, I recommend reading [this](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops.html) and [this](http://svanimpe.be/blog/game-loops-fx.html)

Comment: If `handle` is called at a fixed rate, say every 16ms or so, doesn't this technique introduce jitter by doing updates at 16, 32, 16, 16, 32ms, and so on?

Comment: @StevensMiller Yes, in this case it will affect smoothness (slightly). The links in my previous comment discuss possible solutions to this in a lot of detail. It's not really clear why the OP would want to throttle this beyond the "natural" frame rendering rate of the JavaFX toolkit anyway.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how those links address this issue. It's a major problem for Java which, AFAIK, doesn't actually allow for genuine vsync. Others have said that AnimationTimer provides vsync, but my experiments disprove that easily. Likewise page-flipping (which helps prevent tearing) is another non-solution widely proposed as a way to achieve vsync. Granted, the OP was after something else, but a lot of these problems boil down to not being able to sync-lock to the refresh. Do you know a way?

Comment: @StevensMiller The "temporal aliasing" technique was the technique I was referring to, which provides a mechanism for smoothing changes requested between frames. But in general you are correct that JavaFX is not designed for the low-level animation that you describe (the main use case for JavaFX is desktop business apps, so the API is really designed around making it easy to design UI-control based apps, communicate with services, etc). The toolkit does the rendering; the programmer simply provides what to render and lets the toolkit do its job.

Comment: @StevensMiller So if you're looking to do high-end animation that requires control over the actual rendering process, JavaFX (and probably Java in general) is probably not the best toolkit to use. It's simply not designed with that as a primary use case in mind.

Comment: What I'm actually looking for is a way to block until the next vsync, so I can synchronize my rendering with the refresh rate. That, afaik, is the only way to overcome temporal aliasing (nice phrase, btw; much more elegant than "janking"). In Windows, DirectDraw had a WaitForVerticalBlank method, but that's now deprecated. Haven't yet discovered if Direct2D/3D offers anything comparable.

Comment: @StevensMiller Yup, there is simply no API for that in JavaFX. I think that is substantially different from the question posted here as well, so this is probably not the appropriate place for this discussion. But the bottom line is that JavaFX does not provide hooks into the primitive graphics system at that level. The `AnimationTimer` allows you to execute code on each "pulse", but the control of the pulse generation is - deliberately - buried deep in an impenetrable black box.

Comment: @PhilFreihofner Blog seems to be gone but the associated code repo is [here](https://github.com/svanimpe/fx-game-loops)

Answer (score 4):

Since I already wrote the code and James_D was faster with informing you about you blocking the UI, I still like to add that if you have multiple AnimationTimers of different timings you should create a dedicated class for that. If each of them runs at a different speed, you could implement it like that:

```
import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;

public abstract class AnimationTimerExt extends AnimationTimer {

    private long sleepNs = 0;

    long prevTime = 0;

    public AnimationTimerExt( long sleepMs) {
        this.sleepNs = sleepMs * 1_000_000;
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(long now) {

         // some delay
        if ((now - prevTime) < sleepNs) {
            return;
        }

        prevTime = now;

        handle();
    }

    public abstract void handle();

}
```

Which means that the handle() method is invoked at least after sleepMs milliseconds have passed.

Or you change the parameter and specify the fps, whatever you need.

You can use the above code like this:

```
AnimationTimerExt timer = new AnimationTimerExt(100) {

    @Override
    public void handle() {

        System.out.println( System.currentTimeMillis());

    }
};

timer.start();
```

Also, loading the picture over and over again is not the best choice. If you'd like to do animations, I suggest you take a look at Mike's Blog about [Creating a Sprite Animation with JavaFX](http://blog.netopyr.com/2012/03/09/creating-a-sprite-animation-with-javafx/).

Answer (score 0):

```
new AnimationTimer() {
int frameCount = 0;
        @Override
        public void handle(long currentNanoTime) {

            if (frameCount % 2 == 0) {
             // 30 fps ?
           }         
           frameCount++;
}
```

might be a bit hacky but gets the job done